# Return closest date to a given date in R

Tags: r, date, closest

My data frame consists of individual observations of individual animals. Each animal has a birthdate, that I would like to associate to the closest field season date from a date vector.

Here is a very basic reproducible example:

```
ID <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "a") # individual "a" is measured twice here
birthdate <- as.Date(c("2012-06-12", "2014-06-14", "2015-11-11", "2016-09-30", "2012-06-12"))    
df <- data.frame(ID, birthdate)

# This is the date vector
season_enddates <- as.Date(c("2011-11-10", "2012-11-28", "2013-11-29", "2014-11-26", "2015-11-16", "2016-11-22", "2012-06-21", "2013-06-23", "2014-06-25", "2015-06-08", "2016-06-14"))
```

With the following code, I can get the difference between the birthdate and the closest season enddate.

```
for(i in 1:length(df$birthdate)){
  df$birthseason[i] <- which(abs(season_enddates-df$birthdate[i]) == min(abs(season_enddates-df$birthdate[i])))
}
```

However, what I want is the actual date, and not the difference. For example, the first value of birthseason should be 2012-06-21.

Comment: Are you using the `lubridate` package?

Comment: Would you mind editing the post so the object names in the second part (for loop) use the names in the first part of the example. It's unclear where `younger$HatchCalendarYear1` comes from, for example.

Comment: @Damian I suggested the edits you mention, have a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit confusing since you use variables which you didn't include in your examples.

But I think this is what you want:

```
for (ii in 1:nrow(df))  df$birthseason[ii] <-as.character(season_enddates[which.min(abs(df$birthdate[ii] - season_enddates))])
```

Alternatively using `lapply`:

```
df$birthseason <- unlist(lapply(df$birthdate,function(x) as.character(season_enddates[which.min(abs(x - season_enddates))])))
```

Result:

```
> df
  ID  birthdate birthseason
1  a 2012-06-12  2012-06-21
2  b 2014-06-14  2014-06-25
3  c 2015-11-11  2015-11-16
4  d 2016-09-30  2016-11-22
5  a 2012-06-12  2012-06-21
```

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for which `season_enddate` is the closest to `birthdate[1]`, and `birthdate[2]`, etc.

To get the data straight, I will create an actual reproducible example:

```
birthdate <- as.Date(c("2012-06-12", "2014-06-14", 
                       "2015-11-11", "2016-09-30", 
                       "2012-06-12"))

season_enddates <- as.Date(c("2011-11-10", "2012-11-28", 
                             "2013-11-29", "2014-11-26",
                             "2015-11-16", "2016-11-22", 
                             "2012-06-21", "2013-06-23", 
                             "2014-06-25", "2015-06-08", 
                             "2016-06-14"))
```

Basically I use the function you also used, except that I decided to break it down a bit, so it's easier to follow what you're trying to do:

```
new.vector <- rep(0, length(birthdate))
for(i in 1:length(birthdate)){
    diffs <- abs(birthdate[i] - season_enddates)
    inds  <- which.min(diffs)
    new.vector[i] <- season_enddates[inds]
}

# new.vector now contains some dates that have been converted to numbers:
as.Date(new.vector, origin = "1970-01-01")
# [1] "2012-06-21" "2014-06-25" "2015-11-16" "2016-11-22"
# [5] "2012-06-21"
```

Comment: code looks a lot cleaner here. Maybe edit the question to use the same layout? Makes it much easier to follow.

Comment: Sorry, I must have pasted a part of the code I used on my real dataset by accident... It's fixed now.

Answer (score 2):

All solutions here are essentially the same. If you want to have an optimized function doing this operation for you, this is how I'd do it:

```
match_season <- function(x,y){
  nx <- length(x)
  ind <- numeric(nx)
  for(i in seq_len(nx)){
    ind[i] <- which.min(abs(x[i] - y))
  }
  y[ind]
}
```

Then you can simply do:

```
younger$birthseason <- match_season(younger$HatchDate, season_enddates)
```

Looks cleaner and gives you the desired output in the correct `Date` format.

Benchmarking:

```
start <- as.Date("1990-07-01")
end <- as.Date("2017-06-30")

birthdate <- sample(seq(start, end, by = "1 day"), 1000)

season_enddates <- seq(as.Date("1990-12-21"),
                       as.Date("2017-6-21"),
                       by = "3 months")

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(match_season(birthdate, season_enddates),
          columns = c("test","elapsed"))
```

gives a timing of 7.62 seconds for 100 replications.

Answer (score 1):

I have suggested some edits to your question, so that your example code produces all variables required to reproduce your problem. Please have a look and check that I understood your problem.

To solve it, i suggest to use `which.min` (keeps your code a bit simpler and faster), in combination with subsetting of your `season_enddates` vector, as shown below:

```
for(i in 1:length(younger$HatchCalendarYear)){
  df$birthseasonDate[i] <- season_enddates[which.min(abs(season_enddates - df$birthdate[i]))]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`findInterval` is useful in such cases. Locating the nearest `season_enddates` for each `df$birthdate`:

```
vec = sort(season_enddates)
int = findInterval(df$birthdate, vec, all.inside = TRUE)
int
#[1]  1  5  8 10  1
```

we compare the distance from each of the surrounding dates of the interval and select the minimum:

```
ans = vec[int]
i = abs(df$birthdate - vec[int]) > abs(df$birthdate - vec[int + 1])
ans[i] = vec[int[i] + 1]
ans
#[1] "2012-06-21" "2014-06-25" "2015-11-16" "2016-11-22" "2012-06-21"
```